# Default value and DeferredAttribute problem

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to set the default value in one form from another form. How to do it correctly ???

```
class def_val(models.Model):

    bnumber = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bnumber

class Panel(models.Model):

    barcode = models.CharField('Kod kreskowy', max_length=100, blank=True)
    producer = models.ForeignKey(PanelProducer, verbose_name='Producent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.ForeignKey(PanelSize, verbose_name='Rozmiar', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    box_number = models.CharField(('Numer palety'), max_length=10, blank=True, default=def_val.bnumber)
    tested_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Osoba pakująca', related_name="Created_by", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test_date = models.DateTimeField(('Data pakowania'),default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You don't have any relationship between Panel and def_val, so which instance would be the default? But even if you fixed that, this still wouldn't work because defaults are applied at instantiation time, when you wouldn't even have chosen a def_val. And you don't have any DeferredAttributes here.

Comment: I want that in the application you could once set the default value and after some time from this application change this value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in the model, and neither can you do it in any definition at class level. You would need to do this in the form, in the `__init__` method.

```
class PanelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Panel
        fields = [...]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'box_number' not in self.initial:
            self.initial['box_number'] = def_val.objects.first().bnumber
```